# Python scope inside a nested function inside a class?

Tags: python

How can I set a class variable from inside a function inside another function?

var.py

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
    def seta(self):
        def afunction():
            self.a = 4
        afunction()
    def geta(self):
        return self.a
```

run.py

```
cA = A()
print cA.a
cA.seta()
print cA.a
print cA.geta()
```

python run.py

```
1
1
1
```

why does a not equal 4 and how can I make it equal 4?

Edit:

Thanks everyone - sorry, I just saw now. I accidentally was off by a _ in one of my names.... so my scope is actually all ok.

Comment: You didn't even called `afunction()` in your code.

Comment: You shouldn't change your code to the answer. It is unhelpful, if we have to look through revisions to see what question was answered.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that there are multiple `self` variables.  The argument passed into your inner function overwrites the scope of the outer.

You can overcome this by removing the `self` parameter from the inner function, and making sure you call that function in some way.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
    def seta(self):
        def afunction():  # no self here
            self.a = 4
        afunction()       # have to call the function
    def geta(self):
        return self.a
```

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, `afunction` is never called.  You could do something like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

    def seta(self):
        def afunction(self):
            self.a = 4
        afunction(self)

    def geta(self):
        return self.a

a = A()
print a.a
a.seta()
print a.a
```

Here we actually call `afunction` and explicitly pass it `self`, but this is a rather silly way to set the attribute `a` -- especially when we can do it explicitly without the need for getters or setters:  `a.a = 4`

Or you could `return` the function:

```
def seta(self):
    def afunction(): #Don't need to pass `self`.  It gets picked up from the closure
        self.a = 4
    return afunction
```

and then in the code:

```
a = A()
a.seta()()  #the first call returns the `afunction`, the second actually calls it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside `seta`, you define a function

```
    def afunction(self):
        self.a = 4
```

...that *would* set `self.a` to 4 if it would ever be called. But it's not called anywhere, so `a` is unchanged.

Answer (score -1):

As several others have said, you need to actually *call* functiona at some point.  Comments won't let me type this intelligably so here's an answer:

```
def seta(self):
    def functiona(self):  #defined
        self.a = 4
    functiona()           #called
```

Comment: This should not work. At least in Python 3, you will get an error `missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`. You will need to call `functiona(self)` but still this solution is redundant of defining nested function.

Comment: You didn't notice that this was defining something in the scope of a class in the original question.

Answer (score -1):

How can you make it equate to 4:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 2
        self.c = 3
    def seta(self):
        ##def afunction(self): (remove this)
        self.a = 4 
    def geta(self):
        return self.a
```

Tricky part: Why does is not equate to 4...

Currently a is set to 4 only via "afunction". Since afunction is never called it never executes.. The seta has "afunction" nested inside but not called... similar to member variables within a classs.