# How do i reload the readout via button press in tkinter?

Tags: python, button, tkinter, refresh, reload

I am writing my first usable program. I would like to readout the copies one made from a copier and compare them to a previously saved entry in an external txt file. Because of really long load times I would like to reload the entry without destroying the entire tkinter construct and restart it again. How do I delete the previous entry and readout the entry in the copier "website" from a hidden chrome instance in the background again and again? (The chrome instance is used because of a really unnerving cookie implemented in the copier website logic, if anyone has a solution to not wait like 10 seconds for each copier, I would love to hear more!)

The entire program (the counter.txt file just contains the saved copier 
counter readout, for example: 813981):

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from tkinter import *

    with open('counter.txt', 'r') as file:
        data = file.readlines()
    data = [w.replace('\n', '') for w in data]


    copyshop_dict = {
        "3": {
            "url": "http://192.168.2.50/twelcome.cgi?CorePGTAG=0&Dummy=1558002411080",
            "save": data[2]
        },
        "4": {
            "url": "http://192.168.2.123/twelcome.cgi?CorePGTAG=0&Dummy=1562919772376",
            "save": data[3]
        }
    }


    def browser(url_input):
        global driver
        # create a new hidden Chrome session
        window_size = "1920,1080"
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % window_size)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
        driver.get(url_input)
        python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="javascript:load_device()"]')
        python_button.click()
        python_button2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '//*[@id="navigation"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a/font/b')
        value = python_button2.click()
        return value


    class MyCopySopCounter:
        def __init__(self, parent):

            self.MyParent = parent
            self.MyCounterFrame = Frame(parent)
            self.MyCounterFrame.pack()

            self.backgroundgrid = Frame(self.MyCounterFrame)
            self.backgroundgrid.configure(background='white')
            self.backgroundgrid.grid(column=0, row=0)

            self.title = Frame(self.backgroundgrid)
            self.title.configure()
            self.title.grid(column=0, row=0)

            self.titlelbl = Label(self.title)
            self.titlelbl.configure(text="COPY-QUICK Kopien Zähler", font=("Square721 BdEx BT", 25),
                                    background='white', fg='darkblue')
            self.titlelbl.pack(fill=X)

            self.copierFrame = Frame(self.backgroundgrid)
            self.copierFrame.configure(padx=10, pady=10, background='white')
            self.copierFrame.grid(row=1)

            for key, value in copyshop_dict.items():

                browser(copyshop_dict[key]["url"])

                cofra = Frame(self.copierFrame)
                cofra.configure(width=100, height=100, bd=1, relief=GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10, background='white')
                cofra.grid(column=int(key) - 2, row=0)

                cotifra = Frame(cofra)
                cotifra.grid(column=0, row=0)

                coti = Label(cotifra)
                coti.configure(text="Kopierer %s" % int(key), background='white', fg='darkblue',
                               font=("Square721 BdEx BT", 10), height=2)
                coti.pack()

                html_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//*[@id="mainCounterInformationModule"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]')
                counter = int(html_number.text)

                saved_file_num = int(copyshop_dict[key]['save'])

                if counter > saved_file_num:
                    diff = counter - saved_file_num
                    diff = str(diff)
                    v.set("%s neue Kopie(n)" % diff)

                    self.replace_line('counter.txt', (int(key) - 1), str(counter) + "\n")

                else:
                    v.set("Keine neuen Kopien")

                cocofra = Frame(cofra)
                cocofra.grid(column=0, row=2)

                coco = Label(cocofra)
                coco.configure(text="Kopien:\n%s" % v.get(), background="white")
                coco.pack()

                cobufra = Frame(cofra)
                cobufra.configure(width=200, height=200)
                cobufra.grid(column=0, row=3)

                cobu1 = Button(cobufra)
                cobu1.configure(text="reload", fg='green')
                cobu1.pack(side=LEFT)
                cobu1.bind("<Button-1>", self.refresh(counter, key, coco))

            cobufra = Frame(self.backgroundgrid)
            cobufra.configure(width=200, height=200)
            cobufra.grid(column=0, row=2)

            cobu2 = Button(cobufra)
            cobu2.configure(text="close", fg='red')
            cobu2.pack(side=RIGHT)
            cobu2.bind("<Button-1>", self.button2Click)

            cofrespa = Frame(self.backgroundgrid)
            cofrespa.configure(width=50, height=20, bg='white')
            cofrespa.grid(column=0, row=3)

        def refresh(self, event, key, coco):

            html_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '//*[@id="mainCounterInformationModule"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]')
            counter = int(html_number.text)

            saved_file_num = int(copyshop_dict[key]['save'])

            if counter > saved_file_num:
                diff = counter - saved_file_num
                diff = str(diff)
                v.set("%s neue Kopie(n)" % diff)
                coco.configure(text="Kopien:\n%s" % v.get(), background="white")
                coco.pack()
                self.replace_line('counter.txt', (int(key) - 1), str(counter) + "\n")

            else:
                v.set("No new printouts")
                coco.configure(text=v.get(), background="white")

        def button2Click(self, event):
            root.destroy()

        def replace_line(self, file_name, line_num, text):
            lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
            lines[line_num] = text
            out = open(file_name, 'w')
            out.writelines(lines)
            out.close()


    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Kopierer 3")
    v = StringVar()
    myapp = MyCopySopCounter(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

Thanks to FrainBr33z3 I edited the code, so the refresh function redo the entire logic. And it is still not working. I am not even getting any error message right now! And sadly I am not understanding, why. Like I understand, when I press the `cobu1`-button, it loads the refresh function, which at first readsout the counter-xhtml path and stores it in the variable counter, Then it compares it to the saved number in line of the saved copier in the nested dictionary. And if the readout of the xhtml-path is higher, it should redo the coco label with the difference of the 2 formerly mentioned variables. If not, it should write in the label "No new printouts". I am getting nothing!

Comment: you are missing the `self` keyword. Also `root` is not recognized by the class `MyCopySopCounter` as you have initialized it to `parent`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Where am I missing the .self?

Comment: `def refresh(self):`. To know how scope for nested functions works in python check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368297/python-scope-inside-a-nested-function-inside-a-class)

Comment: This produces the following error message:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
            return self.func(*args)
        TypeError: refresh() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: This seems a problem with your understanding of how the scope of nested functions in class works. How about you define the function `refresh` outside the `for` loop and the `__init__` function. And then call it using `self.refresh()`